# Window width and height and the resize command winapi

Tags: winapi, resize

I was wondering why if I set my window to 1440 x 900 explicitly:

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindow("bla", "bla", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1440/*CW_USEDEFAULT*/, 900/*CW_USEDEFAULT*/, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

When my screen is rendered it must be calling WM_RESIZE and it is passing:

```
    case WM_SIZE:
        screenServer.OnScreenResize( LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam) );
    break;
```

which comes out as 1424 x 861?

Why is that?

Comment: Why the negative vote? If you tell me what's wrong with my question, I can amend it rather than getting the negative vote.

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646.aspx): "The low-order word of lParam specifies the new width **of the client area**. The high-order word of lParam specifies the new height **of the client area**."

Comment: Cheers Remy, absolutely.. I'll keep a much sharper eye out on that. :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can now see that it is the borders of my window that are being accounted for:

[image]